# Can we localize a Bundle?

Tags: bundles

This question came up in a recent presentation:

**Can we localize a Bundle?**

As I understand it we can localize bundle details such as metadata, but not the actual list of items. We can, however, add shared items (from a higher publication) into a Bundle in child publications.

*A basic approach would be to add bundles for content, pages, and functionality at appropriate publications, but then add those bundles in a "publishable" (or "master") publication.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bundles can be localized. However as you have mentioned in your question, items inside the bundle are not localized. A common issue when you have Bundles/Items in a high level publication (Shared) is that if you start a bundle workflow (let's say in the not localized version) then all the items will be locked, that means that you won't be able to start a workflow for the localized bundle because the items are already locked.

A common issue with the behavior described above is for instance you have shared content like a Header, that is used in different platforms (publications), it means that if you start a workflow for the shared content (no localized) you will be publishing items that may not be approved for certain platforms. It sounds like, I want it to be shared for content edition but I don't want it to be shared at publishing/workflow time.

Comment: Good point on the sharing and locking considerations.

Comment: @AlvinReyes just think of a Bundle like a Folder (which it basically is as it's derived from a Virtual Folder). When you localize a Folder, you also don't localize the items in it.

Comment: I should have answered by pointing that out. :-)